# Endpoint URL for external data

Tags: administration

New to Salesforce Admin and still learning. In regards to integration to an external source, I've watched several videos that quickly reference typing in the endpoint, or server URL that your connecting with. Everyone does it so matter of factly as if there is this yellow pages of URLs, but no one ever says what the source is for getting that URL. Is that something we have to ask the clients I.T. team for? I apologize for what may seem to be a rookie question, but again, every tutorial just says what to do with it, but doesn't mention where I get that address.

Thanks,

Land of the lost

Answer (score 0):

Most videos assume that you've already looked at the documentation and/or imported a WSDL (Web Services Definition Language) file into your programming environment. Usually, the URL(s) you need to use for a service are listed in the first couple chapters or in an appendix, but either way, should appear in publicly available documentation. Here's one of several pages ([Implementation Considerations](http://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/implementation_considerations.htm)) that describes which URLs you need to access Salesforce SOAP APIs. Any video I've ever seen assumes that you've probably discovered the necessary URLs beforehand by importing a WSDL file from your organization. Other systems will also likely have a WSDL file, public documentation, or both (usually).

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the service to service, company to company. Company I work for, has a URL Hub where all the important urls are published. Wsdl has a capability to publish the End Point urls so clients can get that info easily but unfortunately not many developers embeds those urls in the wsdl or the one they have is for development servers instead of production ones.